# GCP stored procedure with a query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to merge a table using the output of a query in a stored procedure. Is this possible? If yes, how? This is my sample attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_LOAD()

BEGIN
           
MERGE `T1` 
       USING 
  ############## START of QUERY ###########
SELECT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3  
       FROM T2
       LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2._FIELD4= T1.FIELD1
 ############## END of QUERY ###########
    --return;
   
EXCEPTION
    WHEN error THEN SELECT @@error.message, @@error.statement_text;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST()

BEGIN

MERGE T2 AS t
USING (SELECT a,b,c FROM T1) as s

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MERGE statement regardless it is within a procedure or not.

It is not very clear what is the intent of your query, I provided a sample SQL based on my guess. Please check documentation for how to use the [MERGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement).

```sql
MERGE T1
USING T2
ON T2._FIELD4= T1.FIELD1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(<column_list_of_T1> )
  VALUES(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 )
```

Comment: I am trying to merge the results of a query in to a pre-defined table. (Columns from the query match the columns in pre-defined table). Will your solution work for this?

Comment: T2 in my query could be a subquery (in your words, "results of a query")

Comment: How do I save the results of my select query as a temp table?

Comment: ```MERGE T1
USING SELECT * FROM TABLE 
ON T2._FIELD4= T1.FIELD1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(<column_list_of_T1> )
  VALUES(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 )```

Comment: For temp table, you can simply do `CREATE TEMP TABLE T2 AS SELECT <your_query>` then you can use T2 in MERGE

Comment: I think I am almost there, to create a temp table in GCP I need a begin and end

Comment: I think I am almost there, to create a temp table in GCP I need a BEGIN and END and then another begin and end to do the create/replace procedure for merge. How do i place both of them as i get an error at the moment.       ----QUERY to CREATE a temp TABLE

```BEGIN
CREATE TEMP TABLE T2 AS SELECT * USING mYQUERY
END

--SP to merge above table T2 in to T1

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATASET.LOAD_T1()
BEGIN
    set p_return_message = '';
    
    if upper(p_load_mode) = 'F' then 
        MERGE `T1` AS t
        USING `T2` AS s
           ON FALSE       
END```